# Are we all travelling in the speed of light?

Tags: reference-frames, speed-of-light, relativity

If so then we don't even will know or realise that we are travelling in speed of light because of relativity. We all move in constant velocity and with respect to each other we seems to be in rest as now . Is the whole universe travelling in the speed of light? (Which implies stars produce energy by travellingin speed of light that is e equals m c squared)or just we are travelling in speed of light with relative to other something else?

Comment: Why do you think everything is traveling at the speed of light? Obviously, it is not true. You do see cars and people not traveling $3\times 10^8$ $\text{m}$ in a single second, right? According to the very principles of relativity that you are referring to, no massive particle can ever travel at the speed of light.

Comment: I'm not the down-voter.  I think this is an interesting question because it's been decades, and many volumes of pop.sci., since I've read what used to be the standard reason for a "no" answer to this question, which was that anything travelling at the speed of light would have infinite mass.  I think it gets into an issue called "the measure problem", which has been mentioned a lot since inflationary cosmology arose.  (I hope any answerers will understand that, per Einstein's 1916 popularization of GR, the speed of light in vacuum's "local", and might vary between causally-separated regions.)

Comment: Are we travelling in speed of light relative to something? The relative velocity adds up when two bodies move in opposite direction so can we just run car in half of a speed of light n relatively travel in speed of light?

Comment: My question to the point is are we all travelling in speed of light relatively? not actually?

Comment: Although this question's been put on hold, another recent PSE ?, at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/515366/how-big-is-the-role-of-black-hole-spin-in-forming-its-mass, seems to contain a partial answer to the implicit question, in my comment of two days ago, as to a change in views about the relation of speed to mass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you ask whether we are travelling at a certain speed, you must answer the question 'relative to what?'. Relative to my desk I am not travelling. Relative to a car passing on the street I am travelling at 30mph. Relative to some other star in the Milky Way I may be travelling at thousands of mph. Relative to a proton in the Large Hadron Collider I may be travelling at nearly the speed of light.

You can if you wish say that everything is travelling at the speed of light relative to light, which is simply another way of saying that light travels at the same speed relative to everything it passes, but that is an empty statement and nothing whatever to do with the release of energy from stars.

Answer (score 2):

> Are we all travelling in the speed of light?

No, for the simple reason that, in accord with the Lorentz transformation, any entity with speed $c$ in *an* inertial reference frame has speed $c$ in *all* inertial reference frames (for simplicity, I assume the context of the Special Theory of Relativity).

That is to say, the fact that you have a rest frame, the fact that *you are at rest with respect to yourself*, removes the possibility that you have speed $c$ in *any* inertial reference frame.

Comment: @ Alfred Centauri --This is an especially interesting answer in relation to cosmologies like Poplawski's  inflationary "cosmology with torsion" (described in his 2010 paper by that name, and in numerous other papers about that cosmology--such as "Non-parametric reconstruction of an inflaton potential"--which he's written, or collaborated on, as recently as 2019).  However, in the context of the question at hand, it's hard to understand how the simplifying assumption of SR can be justified. If I'm missing something here, please let me know.